# how to make firefox use alsa audio output (pipewire)

Tags: firefox, audio, alsa, wayland, pipewire

I am having sound issues with my firefox. The problem is that, sound comes off as almost muted and sounds like it is coming out from the back speakers. My firefox is using `wayland`

I've had a similar problem with VLC. I was able to easily fix VLC by setting the audio output module from `pulseaudio audio output` to `ALSA audio output` and selecting `Default ALSA Output (currently PipeWire Media Server)` as the Device.
[like shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShLph.png)

Firefox `about:support` shows the following for the
[audio output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osaXe.png)

when I was installing arch, I installed the following:
`alsa-utils`, `pipewire`, `pipewire-alsa`, `pipewire-pulse`, `pipewire-jack`

my pavucontrol is configured [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc0IM.png).
If I select `Analog Stero Duplex` as the profile, then audio from all sources through firefox works . The only problem is, I can't adjust the volume anymore. The sound is either 0% muted or 100% all the time. With `Pro Audio`, I can adjust volume but some sounds will not work in firefox.

I was able to partially fix the sound issues on firefox by installing `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`. No most youtube videos thru firefox works great. Not all of them work. Some videos still have the same sound issues. I don't know why. For example, this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iarxxm-v9w
Other non-youtube sounds still come off as muted. For example, sounds from this website: https://erogol.github.io/ddc-samples/

If there is a way to configure the alsa/pipewire settings globally, so all applications use it as default, that would be ideal. But getting sound to work on firefox just itself will still be a big win for me either way.

Comment: I am sure that firefox cannot output to ALSA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround solution. I downloaded freetube and the sound on the program works perfectly with all kinds of videoos. With this, I don't have to mess around with ALSA env variables.